# Set Permission to delete file in OS X swift 3.0

Tags: swift, macos, permissions, directory

I coded for osx application to remove file from directory path but I had received error as "couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it". So I want to set access permission code to remove that list of files. If any one have idea or solution please help me. The code as pasted below for reference :

```
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullpath) == true {
                    print("File Available \(fullpath)")
                    do {
                        _ = try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: fullpath)
                    } catch let error as NSError{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
```

In above code, I had found the exist file in directory but I got error that "couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it".

I want to get solution of access permission and remove file from directory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you turn off sandbox in your app target's capabilities?

Comment: No, I had set App Sandbox to ON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your app to be able to access files outside your own app, you need to turn App Sandbox off in your app target's capabilities.

Comment: Okay, I had checked out. But one more issue, it's not selected to turn off. Have you solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean it's not selected to turn off?

Comment: I mean when I choose that button to turn off its not worked. And stay as turn on.

Comment: It's Done. Thank you. @Dàvid Pàsztor